# TextArea Value with break lines

Tags: javascript

I have a form and inside this form a textarea element.
And I want inside this textarea, have break lines.

If I do:

`document.getElementById("myTextarea").value = "Myfirstname\nMylastname";`  `//it works fine`

However if use a variable instead with the same content.

```
var x = "Myfirstname\nMylastname";
document.getElementById("myTextarea").value = x;  //it doesn't show break lines but the characters \n instead.
```

How can I get the variable approach to work properly?

Thx

Comment: Works just fine here when tested.

Comment: What internet browser are you using to test this?

Comment: they are same no differance

Comment: Are you setting X value as you mentioned in question or is it coming from other source  like a database?

Comment: It's coming from database as a string "Myfirstname\nMylastname"

Comment: @Aganeto can you please comment here with dump of x? and also, what is your backend language?

Comment: I suspect that you have to change \n by <br /> and you should be fine. If it works, I elaborate an answer and you can accept.